# Changing default conda command without admin rights

Tags: bash, conda

On a Linux OS, I am having trouble changing `conda` to a different directory. My problem is that I am accessing a device where the default `conda` is linked to a directory in `/somedir/condadir`, but in such device, I am only granted admin rights in `/home/mydir`. When I try to install `miniforge` in `/home/mydir/miniforge`, this is installed correctly, but the conda command is still linked to the previous directory, for which I can't even make an update. I would like to set the `conda` that comes with `miniforge` in `/home/mydir/miniforge` as the default `conda` command. For that, I have tried modifying the `.bashrc` file with my directory, but this does not seem to work: any time I access the device, `conda` still refers to the `/somedir/condadir` part. If Is there an easy way to solve this problem?

Comment: This might be better answered on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) or [Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com). Also, it should all come down to `.bashrc` configuration, but it would help to share the relevant parts to get more precise feedback.